# Generating PDF from HTML with tables and rows

Tags: ios, swift, pdf

I am developing a simple application for creating invoices in Swift for iOS.
For this, I have a simple template HTML with tables and rows (td / tr).

I want to convert this HTML template to a multiple page PDF. It's working like a charm thanks to UIPagePrintRenderer but some rows are duplicated on two pages or the row is cut on the two pages.

I have tried to add css "page-break" on my template. I have a good placement when I print template on a web browser.

But, when I export HTML to PDF (thanks to UIPagePrintRenderer), the CSS styles were not applied on the PDF document, and my elements are duplicated.

I am looking for a better solution to convert HTML to PDF. Any one encountered a similar problem?

**UPDATE :**

Thanks for response guys, below more information of problem and my code.

- First this is my function for convert HTML string to a PDF file.

  ```
  func createPDF(formatter: UIViewPrintFormatter) -> String {

      let render = CustomPrintRenderer()
      render.addPrintFormatter(formatter, startingAtPageAt: 0)
      formatter.maximumContentHeight = 605.0

      let pdfData = NSMutableData()
      UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRect.zero, nil)

      for i in 0...render.numberOfPages {

          UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()

          if(i != 0) {
              render.setupAfterFirstPage()
          }
          render.drawPage(at: i, in: UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds())
      }
      UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()

      pdfFilename = "\(AppDelegate().getDocDir())/Invoice-\(invoiceNumber!).pdf"
      pdfData.write(toFile: pdfFilename, atomically: true)

      return pdfFilename
  }
  ```
- Second, this is my CustomPrintRenderer() class for specified printing zone.

  ```
  class CustomPrintRenderer: UIPrintPageRenderer {

  // A4 Gabarit
  let A4PageWidth: CGFloat = 595.2
  let A4PageHeight: CGFloat = 841.8

  let topPadding: CGFloat = 50.0
  let bottomPadding: CGFloat = 100.0

  let pageInset: CGFloat = 42.5

  //let leftPadding: CGFloat = 100.0
  //let rightPadding: CGFloat = 100.0

  override init() {
      super.init()
      initFrame()
  }

  func initFrame() {
      // Specify the frame of the A4 page.
      let pageFrame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: A4PageWidth, height: A4PageHeight)
      let printable = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: -topPadding, width : A4PageWidth, height: A4PageHeight - topPadding).insetBy(dx: pageInset, dy: pageInset)

      self.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: pageFrame), forKey: "paperRect")
      self.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: printable), forKey: "printableRect")
  }

  func setupAfterFirstPage() {
      let printable = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: topPadding, width : A4PageWidth, height: A4PageHeight - topPadding - bottomPadding).insetBy(dx: pageInset, dy: pageInset)
      self.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: printable), forKey: "printableRect")
  }
  ```

  }
- This is my invoice on HTML (on ios app)
  [image]
- This is my invoice converted to PDF.
  You can see on this screenshots than my items are cropped.
  So, thanks to "page-break" style in css or other way, i want to display a item in next page if the element can not be placed totally on current page.

[image]

**UPDATE 2 :**

- This is my HTML Template :

  Home'Invoice - Invoice

  ```
  body {
      max-width:90%;
      margin:auto;
      padding:30px;
      font-size:16px;
      line-height:24px;
      font-family:'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      color:#485C74;
  }

  /*@media print
  {
    table { page-break-after:auto; }
    tr.items    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto; }
    td.items   { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto; }
    thead { display:table-header-group; }
    tfoot { display:table-footer-group; }
  }*/

  /*@page {
    size: A4;
    margin: 0;
  }

  @media print {
    html, body {
      width: 210mm;
      height: 297mm;
    }
  }*/

  .middle {
      width: 50%;
  }

  .invoice-box table td{
      padding:5px;
      vertical-align:top;
  }

  .logo-images img {
      width:100%; 
      max-width:300px;
      max-height:150px;
  }

  .invoice-box .left-pos {
      text-align: left;
  }

  .invoice-box .center-pos {
      text-align: center;
  }

  .invoice-box .right-pos {
      text-align: right;
  }

  .invoice-box table thead.heading td{
      background:#fab800;
      border-bottom:1px solid #485C74;
      font-weight:bold;
  }

  .invoice-box table{
      width:100%;
      line-height:inherit;
      text-align:left;
  }

  .invoice-box table tr.top table td{
      padding-bottom:20px;
  }

  .invoice-box table tr.top table td.title{
      font-size:45px;
      line-height:45px;
      color:#485C74;
  }

  .invoice-box table tr.information table td{
      padding-bottom:40px;
  }


  .invoice-box table tr.details td{
      padding-bottom:20px;
  }

  .invoice-box table tr.item td, .invoice-box table tr.service td{
      border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
  }

  .invoice-box table tr.item.last td, .invoice-box table tr.service.last td{
      border-bottom:none;
  }

  .invoice-box .items-last, .invoice-box .services-last{
      border-top:2px solid #485C74;
      font-weight:bold;
  }

  footer {
      text-align: center;
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .invoice-box table tr.top table td{
          width:100%;
          display:block;
          text-align:center;
      }

      .invoice-box table tr.information table td{
          width:100%;
          display:block;
          text-align:center;
      }
  }
              </style>
      </head>
      <body>
          <div class="invoice-box">
              <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tbody>

                      <!-- Header Top section -->
                      <tr class="top">
                          <td colspan="5">
                              <table>
                                  <tbody>
                                      <tr>
                                          <td class="logo-images"> <img src="data:image/png;base64, #LOGO_USER#"> </td>
                                          <td class="right-pos"> 
                                              Invoice : ##INVOICE_NUMBER#
                                              <br>
                                              Date : #INVOICE_DATE#
                                              <br>
                                              Due Date : #DUE_DATE# 
                                          </td>
                                      </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                              </table>
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                      <!-- Payment section -->

                      <!-- Informations section -->
                      <tr class="information">
                          <td colspan="5">
                              <table>
                                  <tbody>
                                      <tr>
                                          <td class="middle left-pos"> #SENDER_INFO# </td>
                                          <td class="middle right-pos"> #RECIPIENT_INFO# </td>
                                      </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                              </table>
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                      <!-- Informations section -->
                  </tbody>
              </table>
          </div>

          <div class="invoice-box">
              <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tbody>

                      <!-- Payment section -->
                      <thead class="heading">
                          <td> Payment Method </td>
                      </thead>

                      <tr class="details">
                          <td class="left-pos"> Payment desired : #PAYMENT_METHOD# <br> 
                               A deposit of #PAYMENT_PERCENT# must be paid when signing "good for the agreement" of this invoice, is #PAYMENT_PERCENT_PRICE#.
                          </td>
                      </tr>

                  </tbody>
              </table>
          </div>

          <div class="invoice-box">
              <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tbody>

                      <!-- Items section -->
                      <thead class="heading">
                          <td class="left-pos"> Item / Description </td>
                          <td class="center-pos"> Reference </td>
                          <td class="center-pos"> Quantity </td>
                          <td class="center-pos"> Unit cost </td>
                          <td class="right-pos"> Total Price (excl. tax)</td>
                      </thead>

                      #ITEMS#

                      <tr class="total">
                          <td></td>
                          <td></td>
                          <td></td>
                          <td></td>
                          <td class="right-pos items-last">
                              Subtotal (excl. tax) : #TOTAL_AMOUNT_HT#
                              <br>
                              Sales Tax (#VAT_RAT#) : #VAT_PRICE#
                              <br> 
                              <br>
                              Total (incl. tax) : #TOTAL_AMOUNT_TTC#
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                      <!-- Items section -->

                  </tbody>
              </table>
          </div>

          <footer>
              <div class="footer_content">
                  <hr>
                  <p>Invoice powered By </p>
                  <div class="logo-images"> <img src="data:image/png;base64, #LOGO_FOOTER#"> </div>
              </div>
          </footer>

      </body>
  </html>
  ```
- single_item.html :

  ```
  <tr class="item">
   <td class="left-pos">#ITEM_NAME# <br> #ITEM_DESC#</td>
   <td class="center-pos">#ITEM_REF#</td>
   <td class="center-pos">#ITEM_QUANTITY#</td>
   <td class="center-pos">#ITEM_UNIT_COST#</td>
   <td class="right-pos">#ITEM_TOTAL_PRICE#</td>  
  </tr>
  ```
- last_item.html :

  ```
  <tr class="item last">
   <td class="left-pos">#ITEM_NAME# <br> #ITEM_DESC#</td>
   <td class="center-pos">#ITEM_REF#</td>
   <td class="center-pos">#ITEM_QUANTITY#</td>
   <td class="center-pos">#ITEM_UNIT_COST#</td>
   <td class="right-pos">#ITEM_TOTAL_PRICE#</td>  
  </tr>
  ```

**UPDATE 3 :**

When I added this code on my "item" class, these items have a good page-break but the display is bad. But whitout "display:block;" is still not work :

```
    .item {
    display:block; 
    page-break-inside:avoid; 
    page-break-after: auto;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the original HTML to work on

Comment: I have add HTML Template on my answer. Thanks you for the time to help me !